# Count within HAVING?

Tags: mysql, sql

The question I am trying to answer is What was the gross for each movie that received at least one rating greater than 4 and had a budget of more than $20,000,000?

Return the title of each movie, its budget, and its gross sales.
With the tables set as this:

**Movies_Table**: movie_id, movie_name, release_year, gross_sales, budget
**Actor_Table**: actor_id, actor_name, agent, date_of_birth
**Casting_Table**: casting_id, movie_id, actor_id, role (1 = Lead, 2 = Support)
**Reviews_Table**: reviews_id, reviewer_name, movie_id, rating (1, 2, 3, 4 or 5)

The code that I wrote up is this but I'm not sure I can use a COUNT as I have it.

Can I use HAVING like I have it shown here to get the results above?

```
SELECT m.movie_name, m.budget, m.gross_sales
FROM Movies_Table as m
JOIN Reviews_Table as rev on m.movie_id = rev.movie_id
WHERE m.budget >= 20000000
HAVING(COUNT(rev.rating >= 4)) > 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `SUM` instead of `COUNT` as result of condition will be either 0 or 1. Also, add the relevant group by clause.

Something like this:

```
select m.movie_name,
    m.budget,
    m.gross_sales
from Movies_Table as m
join Reviews_Table as rev on m.movie_id = rev.movie_id
where m.budget >= 20000000
group by m.movie_name,
    m.budget,
    m.gross_sales
having sum(rev.rating >= 4) > 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you need only values form movie table rather than join you can use below sql.

**I have written this sql for oracle. 
syntax may be change according to your database server.**

```
SELECT m.movie_name, m.budget, m.gross_sales
FROM Movies_Table as m
WHERE m.budget >= 20000000
  AND exists (select 'x' from Reviews_Table as rev
              where m.movie_id = rev.movie_id
                and rev.rating >= 4)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this...

```
select m.movie_name,
        m.budget,
        m.gross_sales
    from Movies_Table as m
    join Reviews_Table as rev on m.movie_id = rev.movie_id
    where m.budget >= 20000000 and  rev.rating >= 4
    group by movie_name
```

Comment: This won't even run because you have two fields that are not in the group by or aggregates...